# Group comments by posts id in an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

When I fetch my comments from the server, it comes as an array of comments.

```
[
    { content: "foo1", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo2", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo3", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo4", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo5", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo6", postId: 3 }
]
```

I would like to group them in an object like:

```
{
    1: [
        { content: "foo1", postId: 1 },
        { content: "foo2", postId: 1 },
        { content: "foo3", postId: 1 }
    ],
    2: [
        { content: "foo4", postId: 2 },
        { content: "foo5", postId: 2 }
    ],
    3: [
        { content: "foo6", postId: 3 }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure it's easy and I tried many combination with lodash using groupBy or keyBy with assign but I still didn't find a correct answer. I'm using lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var array = [
    { content: "foo1", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo2", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo3", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo4", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo5", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo6", postId: 3 }
    ];

var formatedData = _.groupBy(array, 'postId');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use _.groupBy from lodash with a functional callback to return postId like

```js
const arr = [
    { content: "foo1", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo2", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo3", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo4", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo5", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo6", postId: 3 }
]

console.log(_.groupBy(arr, function(obj) { return obj.postId}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With **ES6** you can try this:

```
const grouped = comments.reduce((map, comment) => {
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(comment.postId)) 
       map[comment.postId] = []
    map[comment.postId].push(comment)
    return map
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this way:

```js
var array = [
    { content: "foo1", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo2", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo3", postId: 1 },
    { content: "foo4", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo5", postId: 2 },
    { content: "foo6", postId: 3 }
];
var result = {};
array.map(current=>{
    //find key
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(current.postId)){
        //exist the key postId, let add
        result[current.postId].push(current);
    }else{
        //not exist key postId, add new object to result
        result[current.postId] = [];
        Object.assign(result[current.postId], [current]);
    };
});
console.log(result);
```